# childs in scrollbar is hiding in time of scroll

Tags: c++, fltk

I have one Fl_Group item, inside it I have  a Scrollbar, inside scrollbar one Fl_Group and in group many childs  (Fl_Box items ). In time of scroll child items is hiding when first box item outside of top
[image]

```
Box::Box(MyOverlayWindow *win, Point p1, Point p2,
        Size s1, Size s2, const char *L)
           :Fl_Group(p1.x(),p1.y(),100,100,L),
         m_x0(p1.x()),m_y0(p1.y()),m_x1(p2.x()),m_y1(p2.y()),
         start_size(s1), end_size(s2)

{
    set_start_size(start_size);
    oly = win;
    Fl_Scroll *scroll = new Fl_Scroll(x()+5,y()+5,w()-15,h()-15);
    scroll->box(FL_ROUNDED_BOX);
    scroll->color(FL_WHITE);
    group = new  Fl_Group(x()+5,y()+5,scroll->w()-15,40000);
    group->box(FL_ROUNDED_BOX);
    group->color(FL_WHITE);
    std::vector<std::string> image_names;
    put_lines_to_vector(image_names);
    for(int i=0; i < 1500 ; i++) {
    SimpleBox *b1 = new SimpleBox(Point(group->x(),(i*60)+group->y()+5),
                Size(group->w()-5, 60),"SimpleBox");
        b1->add_image(image_names[i]);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I added line of code inside for circle, every time when I create a child I need to add it to Fl_Group widget

```
for(int i=0; i < 1500 ; i++) {
SimpleBox *b1 = new SimpleBox(Point(group->x(),(i*60)+group->y()+5),
            Size(group->w()-5, 60),"SimpleBox");
    b1->add_image(image_names[i]);
    group->add(b1); <-------------
}
```